# first in first out pairing in list when cumulative sum cross 0

Tags: python, list

I am trying to achieve a FIFO pairing

assuming that I have a list such has BUY/SHORT quantities and SELL/COVER quantities in a list such as:

```
x = [100.0, -100.0, 100.0, 100.0, -200.0, 200.0, -100.0, -100.0, 100.0,-100.0]
```

I am trying to isolate buys and sell such has the sum of them equal 0.

```
i.e. x[0] is offset with x[1]
x[2] and x[3] is offset with x[4]
```

I am trying to get a nested list of index position of the list x that look like this:

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2, 3], [4]], [[5], [6, 7]], [[8], [9]]]
```

I would expect the exact same result if the initial list was reverse like :

```
x = [-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, -200.0, 100.0, 100.0, -100.0,100.0]
```

So pretty much, every time the cumulative sum cross 0, I reset the pairing.

Any help is appreciated!

I have achieve a partial solution where a list has perfect offset size such has:

```
def find_matching_position(trade_list):
    solutions = list(zip([i for i, x2 in enumerate(trade_list) if x2 == trade_list[0]],
                         [i for i, x2 in enumerate(trade_list) if x2 == trade_list[0] * -1]))

    return [sorted(x) for x in solutions]

x = [100, 100, -100 , 100, -100, -100]

    find_matching_position(x)
    [[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter added where I am right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x = [-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, -200.0, 100.0, 100.0, -100.0,100.0]
current_sum = 0
current_sub = 0
t1 = []
t2 = []
t3 = []
for i, a in enumerate(x):
   if a >= 0:
      if (current_sum + a)+current_sub == 0:
          t1.append(i)
          t2.append([t1, t3])
          t1 = []
          t3 = []
          current_sum = 0
          current_sub = 0
       else:
          current_sum += a
          t1.append(i)
   else:
       if current_sum + (current_sub + a) == 0:
           t3.append(i)
           t2.append([t1, t3])
           t1 = []
           t3 = []
           current_sum = 0
           current_sub = 0
       else:
           current_sub += a
           t3.append(i)

print(t2)
```

Output:

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2, 3], [4]], [[5], [6, 7]], [[8], [9]]]
```

Comment: interesting approach, works fine if its starts with a positive number, but doesnt work the other way around! checking for modification

Comment: @StevenG Please see my recent edit. It now works for both.

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit more compact:

```
def split_seq( seq ):
    result = []
    sum = 0
    subseq = [[],[]]
    for i,a in enumerate(seq):
        sum += a
        subseq[ 0 if a>=0 else 1 ].append( i )
        if sum == 0:
            result.append( subseq )
            subseq = [[],[]]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt (Python 2.7):

```
x = [100.0, -100.0, 100.0, 100.0, -200.0, 200.0, -100.0, -100.0, 100.0,-100.0]
MasterList, Pos, Neg = [], [], []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] >= 0:
        Pos.append(i)
    else:
        Neg.append(i)
    if sum([x[n] for n in Pos]) + sum([x[n] for n in Neg]) == 0:
        if Pos[0] < Neg[0]:
            MasterList.append([Pos, Neg])
        else:
            MasterList.append([Neg, Pos])           
        Pos, Neg = [], []

print MasterList
```

Output:

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2, 3], [4]], [[5], [6, 7]], [[8], [9]]]
```

Output for `x = [-1, -1, -1, 2, 1, -3, 1, 2]`:

```
[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5], [6, 7]]]
```